# Copying large file with robocopy during remote-desktop session failed with ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, file-transfer, robocopy

Today, it was necessary for me to copy a rather large file from one PC A to another PC B. I'm using Windows on both PCs, so that I thought robocopy would be the tool of my choice. The file was about 2GB is size.

For this I used robocopy as a tool, where I mounted a drive X: from PC A in the remote-desktop session, so that is accessible on B.

Now, robocopy started to copy the file, but after 5% of progress it was always the case that the following error occurs and copying was starting again and again.

It says the following error code: `0x000003E3 ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED`, being described by:

```
The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
```

Does anyone knows the reason for this kind of error?